# Is there a way to adjust the torch/flash brightness level on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, camera

I've read plenty of topics on adjusting the screen brightness but is it possible to do the same with the flash or is it a binary on/off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In IOS 6+, you can.

```
[myAVCaptureDevice setTorchModeOnWithLevel:0.5 error:NULL]; <== range is (0,1.0] (don't send 0)
```

You can enumerate the av capture devices like so:

```
NSArray * devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
```

and determine which have torches (i.e. not microphones :):

```
myAVCaptureDevice.hasTorch
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I've tried this method to reduce the brightness, but even with a very small value (0.001), it's still blindingly bright.  Is that what I should expect?  I can't discern much difference between full and low brightness.  (I'm using iOS 8 and iOS 9.)

Comment: Yeah, there's not a huge difference.   It never goes to what a human being would call "dim".

Comment: That sucks :( I am trying to make a barcode scanner for a custom barcode that uses magnetic ink, turning on the light helped a lot to read most of the barcode, but whatever is right below the light shines so brighly that the metal in the ink overcomes the rest, and the thing starts to shine like a mirror, completely inverting the color (ie: the ink is black, thus I look for black bars, but below the light it shines white)

Comment: I don't think LEDs function at a wide variety of brightnesses.   I don't think it's a software limitation.

Answer (score -1):

The torch itself is on/off but you can control "manually" when to turn it on and when off (you would need to use NSTimer for that).

Maybe you can do it fast enough so the light would look dimmed (I don't really know if that would work practically).

You can start with iStrobe (open source) and check it out easily:
http://www.vellios.com/istrobe/

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work very well. Even locking the device for configuration, then running a loop on a high priority thread that toggles the torch on/off rapidly with different duty cycles. No mater what timing I used, it still flashed visibly at somewhere around 5-10 flashes per second, and did not vary the apparent brightness.

Comment: It was just a suggestion. I haven't tried it myself. It's good to know that isn't feasible (but it's weird).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, in ios6+ you can adjust the brightness level.  There is a property to adjust level of brightness ... the value range from 0.0 to 1.0

Comment: @H Bastan, the torchLevel property is read only, and was added in iOS 5. There is a new method in iOS 6, setTorchModeOnWithLevel:error: as mentioned by xaxxon, above, that does let you set the brightness from iOS 6 or later.