# How to Put Slider that increase decrease brightness of camera in AVCaptureSession

Tags: iphone, ios, avcapturesession

so far i have presented camera put one slider in that which zoom zoom out camera now but now I want to Put another Slider which increase and decrease brightness of camera I have searched on this and i need to use AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and taking single frame which i can get on delegate method and process it and do what you want to do with that frame I am posting my code below and explain other things in it

```
    AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
   // AVCaptureVideoDataOutput
    if (videoDevice) {
        NSError *error;
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoIn = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:&error];
        if (!error) {
            if ([[self captureSession] canAddInput:videoIn])
                [[self captureSession] addInput:videoIn];
            else
                NSLog(@"Couldn't add video input");     
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"Couldn't create video input");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create video capture device");

    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *videoOut = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    /*
     RosyWriter prefers to discard late video frames early in the capture pipeline, since its
     processing can take longer than real-time on some platforms (such as iPhone 3GS).
     Clients whose image processing is faster than real-time should consider setting AVCaptureVideoDataOutput's
     alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames property to NO.
     */
    [videoOut setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];
    [videoOut setVideoSettings:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey]];
    dispatch_queue_t videoCaptureQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Video Capture Queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    [videoOut setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:videoCaptureQueue];
    dispatch_release(videoCaptureQueue);
    if ([captureSession canAddOutput:videoOut])
        [captureSession addOutput:videoOut];
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{

      I HAVE READ THAT NEED TO PROCESS FRAME AND THEN SEND IT BACK TO SESSION BUT HOW I DONT KNOW 
        THIS IS THE DELEGATE METHOD WHERE I GET FRAME NOW I DONT UNDERSTAND HOW TO PROCESS THIS 
FRAME WHAT SHOULD I DO SO I CAN INCREASE AND DECREASE BRIGHTNESS OF CAMERA PLEASE HELP ME IF YOU KNOW 
  }
```

Comment: My bad sir forgiveness

Comment: come in iphone-ipad room here is link  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/iphone-ipad

Comment: Can you help me out? I also want to increase decrease brightness of front camera. I have created AVCaptureSession.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that just set Brightness of mainScreen with bellow code..

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:sliderValue];
```

in slider value set value from 0 to 1 like bellow..

```
yourSlider.minimumValue = 0.f;
yourSlider.maximumValue = 1.0f;
```

and its `UIControlEventValueChanged` call any method like bellow and change the value , see bellow Example..

```
- (void)Brightness_Changed:(UISlider *)sender
{
    [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:sender.value];
}
```

Comment: my brother parash dont want to change brightness of mainScreen need to take frame from camera and process on it and then brighting it up and returning back to AVCaptureSession. that delegate method get called continuously with current frame of camera

Comment: you wrote that increase decrease camera so its a way that you can do that so i post this answer and its working also :)

Comment: i have tried it but its changing device brightness which we dont want. and its between only 0 and 1 cant do more than that brightness like sun and and darkness like night can only be achieved by frame processing :(

Comment: yes its working like that For example alpha or sun and night but here you want to do this process only on in one view or part of this mainscreen right??

Comment: Parash one more thing when we do the way you said it so yes device brightness is getting increased and decreased so when user press home button then we should change brightness back to normal right? so for that i tried applicationinbackground app delegate method i set brightness to 1 and did not work then i tried default notification but it did not worked too have any idea

Comment: yes in `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` method set 1 try it out and let me know.. :)

Comment: tried its not working actually viewwilldisappear will not get called if user directly press home button

Comment: try it out in this method - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{        
     [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:1.0f];        
}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34444/discussion-between-paras-joshi-and-java)

Comment: i have set it 1 everything possible but its not working man. and brightness is not like so really bright its so so normal i need brightness like whole screen become white and we decrease it at lowest point then it should be black screen like that torch application

Comment: then for that i give one suggestion i dont know you like it or not but get one UIImageView and set on whole screen when you want to display the brightness and darkness at that time just unhide it and set alpha with slider value and set its backGround color to Black

Comment: @java see bro this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852173/is-there-a-way-to-adjust-the-torch-flash-brightness-level-on-an-ios-device for torch flash light get something from this :)

Answer (score 1):

@Paras Joshi answer is working perfect

i am just updating answer for swift user

```
@IBOutlet weak var slider : UISlider!
```

set slider minimum value to 0 and maximum to 1 and then in view did load just set the current value of slider to main screen.

```
UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(slider.value)
```

finally create action of slider value change and give value to main screen

```
@IBAction func slider_value_changed(_ sender: UISlider) {
    UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(sender.value)
}
```

you are all set build and run your project