# Can I changed camera flash brightness level?

Tags: ios, camera, ios-camera

I want create simple application such as [android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ihandysoft.flashlight.led.free).

Camera properties have only "on" / "off" flash as i known.
Can i change flash brightness? Maybe some libs will help me?

Comment: Possible duplication:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852173/is-there-a-way-to-adjust-the-torch-flash-brightness-level-on-an-ios-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can from iOS 6.0 on.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009520-CH1-SW90) is your friend.

The method you are looking for is [setTorchModeOnWithLevel:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009520-CH1-SW3)

Also make sure to read the discussion part of method description. Not all devices support setting the `torchlevel`.